# How to do pagination if next button not available

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get data by using Scrapy and I'm facing this table where number and letters are included for pagination. And there are around 116 pages. So how can i iterating till 116. here is the site [URL](https://www.shalexp.com/texas/companies). Please have a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's sample code which will extract pagination links from list pages.
You should do it on each list page. Scrapy will handle duplicated links automatically - it will visit only newly discovered pages.

```
def parse_list(self, response):
    pagination = response.css('a.page-link::attr(href)').re(r'.+?page.+')
    for url in pagination:
        yield response.follow(
            url=url,
            callback=self.parse_list
        )
```